# Is there a simple way to convert Tkinter to matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I need to modify the following code to print bar graph of the cluster populations. Briefly it stores all values in numpy arrays and than print the bar histogram (indicating number of conformations in each clusters on Y, and some inherent value of the cluster (energy) on X) using Tkinter module, which seems to be not very practical solution..

```
r = Tkinter.Tk()
        dataList = []
        reverseList = []
        rLctr = 0
        confL = d.ch.conformations
        e = d.clusterer.energy_used
        #for l in mol.cluSEQ:
        for l in d.clusterer.clustering_dict[cut_off]:
            dataList.append([l[0].energy, len(l)])
            reverseList.append(range(rLctr, rLctr+len(l)))
        mol.elist = numpy.array(elist)
        mol.r = [numpy.minimum.reduce(mol.elist), 
                    numpy.maximum.reduce(mol.elist)]
        mol.nbins = Tkinter.IntVar()
        mol.nbins.set(10)
        mol.min = Tkinter.StringVar()
        mol.min.set(str(mol.r[0]))
        mol.max = Tkinter.StringVar()
        mol.max.set(str(mol.r[1]))
    
        r = (float(mol.min.get()), float(mol.max.get()))
        mol.ehist = HistogramRI(mol.elist,mol.nbins.get(),range=r)
        mol.ehist.createReverseIndex()
        nodeList = mol.ehist.array
        tstr = mol.name + ' histogram'
        top = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        top.title(tstr)
        mol.ehist
        #top = Tkinter.Toplevel()
        xlabel = 'ENERGY'+ 'clusterized with ' + str(cut_off) + 'A'
        mol.clustNB = InteractiveHistogramGraph(mol.name,
                master=top, nodeList = dataList, reverseIndex=reverseList,
                xlabel_text=xlabel, 
                ylabel_text='#\nC\nO\nN\nF\nO\nR\nM\nA\nT\nI\nO\nN\nS')
        mol.clustNB.draw.update()
        mol.clustNB.draw.postscript({'file':outputfilename, 'colormode':'color'})
        top.update_idletasks()
```

Could you suggest me a simple way to convert it to the matplot lib in order that I could control all printing options?

Comment: Probably faster to start from scratch!

Comment: Actually, I have already seen many reverse topics when people asked how to integrate mat-plot lib into tkinter interphace so I thought that it could be a trivial task, dealing with simple graphs ...

Comment: It is trivial to create a simple matplotlib bar chart - it is also trivial to embed a matplotlib canvas in a tkinter frame - it is not at all trivial to reverse engineer some sort of drawing on a tkinter canvas, and adapt it to matplotlib... Your best approach is probably to extract the data, and recreate a matplotlib chart (throw away the tkinter bits).